# Outlier treatment in Vector Autoregression (VAR) Model using vars package in r

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

I have the same problem as the following post, but I have more samples and the index of the outlier is known.

[Outlier treatment in Vector Autoregression (VAR) Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73304/outlier-treatment-in-vector-autoregression-var-model?newreg=31eda9f1618047dcba346fdcb8014dcb)

I tried deleting the outliers; it works. I also want to try including dummy variables for the outliers (the dummy take the value of 1 on the outliers, and zero otherwise) and compare the two treatments. One reason I want to do this is that a special event at t1 may also impact the response variable y2 at t2. However, its impact on t2 is not significant enough, thus y2 is not an outlier.

`Question`: The VAR in R package `vars` returns "NAs in dummy variable". I guess is because the dummy variable comprises a lot of zeros. I don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is a programing question you might be better off at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought people here might meet the same problem. I don't understand why the VAR model in R allows no zero value in variables.